# SaneTwain won't run on WIN 10

Tags: windows-10, scanner, sane

I am trying to use SaneTwain v1.37 under Win 10 Pro 64 bi6 v2iH2 to connect to a Scan Server ( Raspberry Pi, Buster)

There aren't may posts on this subject but all I have found seem to be about features. This indicates that it is running. All I get is a series of error messages.

Before Home screen appears:
`There is no default printer currently selected.`

Then: `Error establishing connection to host` but correct ip address shows in Tools screen.

Printer option opens with blank or sometimes OneNote, and occasionally with connected printers.

Prog cannot be closed with "X", this produces `Access Violation at address 004056A9 in scanimage.exe Read of address 00000004`

The only method of terminating is by using Task Manager + End Task

The SANE Server scans locally, `scanimage -L` is OK and udev and saned.socket is active.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not fully sure but haven't MS removed TWAIN in favor of WIA from Windows some years ago?

Comment: SaneTwain is old, try [SANEWinDS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sanewinds/).

Comment: I tried SANEwinDS but was put off by the pdf scanner app. I preferreed the full toolset of scanimage. I also got an error "Unable to read from the data connection. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." The saned.socket status was active. Presumably this is the same reason why SaneTwain cant connect.  Not sure about Twain support but there is a windows\twain_32 folder.